# PySimpleGui Travando a janela

Tags: python, while, layout, pyautogui

Com esse código minha janela trava após eu clicar em iniciar, objetivo é no momento que eu clicar em iniciar, o script execute e a janela continue aberta para que eu consiga pausar/parar pelo botão 2.

```
def iniciar():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Clique abaixo para iniciar ou pausar:')],
        [sg.Button('iniciar'), sg.Button('Pausar')]
    ]
    return sg.Window('iniciar', layout=layout)


window = iniciar()
while True: 
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Pausar':
        break    
    if event == 'iniciar':
        print('iniciando script')
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que esteja "travando" por conta do time.sleep que você colocou no final. Eu já tive esse problema e era por conta disso. Retirei do meu código e funcionou, faz o teste de retira-lo e vê se funciona. Se essa pausa no final, realmente for necessário para o seu código funcionar, substitua pelo comando "pause" da lib os.system.
Visite: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system